# Expand variable inside curly braces, inside single quotes, inside double quotes

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that takes a variable and populates it inside a somewhat complex string and I can't figure out how to get it to work.

I have the following bash code..

```
PWD="foobar"
curl -XPOST "localhost/api/user/bob" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"password" : "${PWD}"}
```

what I want to have happen is obviously this:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost/api/user/bob" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"password" : "foobar"}
```

but none of the iterations and expansion "tricks" I know seem to work because of the braces and the single and double quotes.

I've tried

```
$PWD
${PWD}
```

Both to no avail.

Comment: `PWD` is already used by the shell; choose a different variable name (that isn't all caps).

Comment: As far as the shell is concerned, what you have is a single-quoted string. The double-quotes, braces, dollar-sign, etc have no syntactic significance to the shell, because they're in single-quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to allow the `$PWD` to expand. (The braces are irrelevant here.)

```
-d "{\"password": \"$password\"}"
```

Better yet, though, use something like `jq` to generate JSON so that you can be sure everything is quoted correctly without shell interference.

```
-d "$(jq -n --arg p "$password" '{password: $p}')"
```

Comment: when I do that, VSCode seems to think that my quotes are unbalanced (I think is what's happening).

Comment: That's VSCode's problem, not yours.

Comment: I just needed to escape the second "internal" double quote.. 




-d "{\"password\": \"$password\"}" thanks for the help

Comment: Excellent advice to use jq to generate valid JSON